# Why can't a function with return value be assigned to a pointer function with void?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, void-pointers

In C/C++, the following code works perfectly fine.

```
void *pa;
void fa(void*);

int a; // or any type
pa = &a;
fa(&a);
```

I'm confused why this isn't true for function's return type:

```
   void fa(void);
   int fb(void);
   void (*pa)(void);
   int (*pb)(void);

   pa = fa; pb = fb; // OK
-> pa = fb; // Wrong, why???
   pb = fa; // Wrong, but reasonable
```

Since the return type of `fb` can be well discarded (i.e. call `fb()` directly without using its return value), why doesn't the marked line work?

And for this the compiler still complains.

```
   void* fa(void);
   int* fb(void);
   void* (*pa)(void);
   int* (*pb)(void);

   pa = fa; pb = fb; // OK
-> pa = fb; // Wrong, why???
   // pb = fa;

[Error] invalid conversion from 'int* (*)(void)' to 'void* (*)(void)' [-fpermissive]
```

I have totally no idea why...

Comment: It's wrong because they're different types. Furthermore, C++ slightly reduces the scope of the general `void *` idiom. Back in the days of C you had to use `void *` in many situations for convenience. C++ discourages the use of `void *`, and emphasizes proper type-safe design. Whatever you're trying to do here, it's wrong. You need to figure out how to properly implement what you're doing, in a 100% type-safe manner, without messing around with `void *`.

Comment: It's not clear at all what the first piece of code has to do with the other. Note that "void" does not mean the same thing everywhere - in `void*` it means "anything", but on its own it means "nothing".

Comment: @molbdnilo This code `int* f(void); void* (*pf)() = f;` makes compiler complain `[Error] invalid conversion from 'int* (*)(int)' to 'void* (*)(int)' [-fpermissive]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your source code ignores a returned value, it's still returned from the function when it's called and the compiler has to generate code to deal with it.
To put it another way: it's only ignored in the source code, not by the executing program.

If you have

```
int fa() {return 0;}
//...
something();
fa();
somethingelse();
```

it's equivalent to

```
int fa() {return 0;}
//...
something();
{  // Scope that delimits the returned value's lifetime.
    int imgonnaignorethismmkay = fa();
} // End special scope, destroy the return value.
somethingelse();
```

If `pa = fb` were allowed, there would be no way for the compiler to know that there's a returned value that it needs to get rid of if you call `pa()`.

---

On your third case:

"function that returns `int*`" is completely unrelated to "function that returns `void*`.
You'll see the same error if you try

```
char f(); 
int(*p)() = f;
```

even though you can convert a char to an int.

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns an int is not a function that returns void. You can call a function and ignore its return value, but when you create a pointer to function the type must match exactly. To use a function that returns int in a context that requires something that returns void, use `std::function`; it handles impedance mismatches in arguments and return types.